# Modify column with first and last characters

Tags: mysql

I have a column with credit card numbers in different formats. Some have dashes some don't. I need the first character and the last four formatted like this:

5-1234

Just want to run a UPDATE query from the console. I know how to get the first and last but can't get the union right. Here is my code.

```
UPDATE table
SET credit_no = LEFT(credit_no, 1)
union "-"
union SUBSTRING(credit_no, -4, 4);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET credit_no = CONCAT(LEFT(credit_no, 1), "-", RIGHT(credit_no, 4));
```

Or even:

```
UPDATE table SET credit_no = CONCAT_WS('-', LEFT(credit_no, 1), RIGHT(credit_no, 4));
```

See Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html